# How to display all subpages and short by year

Tags: theme-development, customization, shortcode, child-pages

How can I display all child-pages and short by year in Wordpress

For example:
all subpages in `2016, 2017, 2018`:

• **2018**:

> ----- Subpage A
>
> ----- Subpage B
>
> ----- Subpage C

• **2017**:

> ----- Subpage A
>
> ----- Subpage B
>
> ----- Subpage C

• **2015**:

> ----- Subpage A
>
> ----- Subpage B
>
> ----- Subpage C

Your time amend help is greatly appreciated.

My code

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

global $post; 

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Comment: What you have done till now? Share the code.

Comment: Is it possible to group all subpages by year?